# Google Chrome shows space between <buttons>

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have problem with CSS `<buttons>` in Google Chrome, it shows space between `<buttons>`, but in Opera and IE it is OK, why?

Here is the full CSS code:

```
button {
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
    font: bold 11px Sans-Serif;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #666;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<div><button type="button">Send</button><button type="button">Reset</button></div>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a left margin as well. This corrects it in Chrome (not sure what it'll do in other browsers)... I edited the margin property.

```
button {
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
font: bold 11px Sans-Serif;
padding: 6px 8px;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #666;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, white, #E0E0E0);
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each set of buttons is contained within a `div` which has a `margin-left` of three (3) pixels.

**EDIT** Chrome also applies a default margin of one (1) pixel.  You need to set the margin to zero (0) for the buttons to get rid of this spacing.

Comment: I believe he's referring to the fact that there is a 1px space between the other buttons (in Chrome only).

Comment: @TimothyAaron I noticed that when I looked back.